# How to indent a selection in gVim (Win32)

Tags: windows, vim, indentation

I'd like to **indent a block of text**.

I am able to do this in the **Linux** build of gVim.

I do this in the **state** of gVim where I'm not in the insert or visual mode. The bar at the bottom is blank on the left, and the line number and percentage are showing on the right hand side.

Then I perform the following **procedure**: I select a block of text via click and drag. Then I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>. After that, I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> and the block of text will move over a tab.

If I do this in **Windows** however, it just replaces the block with `>`.

I am just running the stock Windows **rc file** and version 7.1 of gVim.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/how-do-i-indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi

Comment: ( hopefully that solves problem, if not, say so )

Comment: It doesn't, my question is specifically about the win32 build of gvim. The solution to the question you're referring to does not work for win32.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you first enter SHIFT-V, and than shift+arrows to select the text, it will indent.
You can also use SHIFT-V, and use 'hjkl' to select the block.

If you use shift+arrows or the mouse to select a block of text, it does not work and the selection will be replaced with a '>'. This can be changed when you change selectmode;

set selectmode=mouse,key

- default setting after behave mswin

set selectmode=key

- now you can select with the mouse and press '>' to indent

set selectmode=

- now you can select both with the mouse and shifted arrow keys and press '>' to indent

If you add this to your vimrc, do it after behave mswin

Comment: If I esc out of modes, hit shift + v, release the v but continue to hold shift I am able to use the mouse to select to some extent.

Thanks!

Comment: I also had to add `set keymodel=startsel,stopsel` to make it work as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Related to this, I use a handy remap for visual mode that allows indenting the text multiple times while keeping your text selected.  Similar to how visual studio lets you select and hit tab (or shift-tab) to indent.

Add the following to your .vimrc

```
" Pressing < or > will let you indent/unident selected lines
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
```

Also you can use == to have vim try and determine the correct indenting automatically.  It will work on any line buy just placing the cursor there and pressing == or you can do fancy stuff like select the entire file and press == to fix all the indenting (works wonders on html generated by wysiwyg editors).

Comment: Good one, but I just use "." (dot) to indent previously indented lines: Vjj>. (repeat dots as necessary)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> -> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> -> Select Lines -> <kbd>></kbd> <kbd>></kbd>

Comment: This also results in the selection being replaced with a '>'.

Comment: When I do this, it indents the block about 5 spaces but I want just to indent 1 or 2 spaces. How can I do that? (thank you)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `behave mswin` to `behave xterm` in your vimrc file.

Comment: I like some of the mswin behavior though. It seems like I should be alternative shortcut or a way to configure a shortcut to do the same thing.

Comment: It looks like the answer you're looking for was provided by Wimmel in his explanation of the selectmode setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use text objects if you want to avoid visual mode entirely.  For example `>ap` in Normal mode indents one paragraph, `>aB` indents one curly-brace block, etc.  See `:h text-objects`.