# How can I indent code in the Vim editor on Windows?

Tags: winapi, vim, indentation

#### Duplicate:

> [How to indent a selection in gvim (win32)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318923/how-to-indent-a-selection-in-gvim-win32)
>
> [How do I indent multiple lines quickly in vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/how-do-i-indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi)

Using vim under linux I can indent a block of code using the VISUAL mode and pressing ">".
In vim under Windows this does not happen.

This is what happens:

- Press V, the VIM enter in the VISUAL mode
- Press 'Down', the VIM exit for the VISUAL mode. I can't select anything in VISUAL mode.

Alternatively, if I use the SELECT mode for selecting code the ">" does not indent it.

Comment: indent is the name of a command that "indent". Why not indentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I got it. In Windows I should press Shift+Down to remain in the VISUAL mode.

Comment: this is the correct answer. 
press v then hold shift and press down to select the text.

Answer (score 6):

Haven't you keep mswin.vim ? If you want the same behaviour on both OSes, get rid of this file.

Comment: This is the correct answer. mswin.vim is evil and causes a lot of basic vim functionality to change and/or act differently.

Answer (score 4):

If you use V (uppercase) you enter VISUAL LINE mode. For VISUAL mode you should use v (lowercase).

And if you use the standard movement keys (hjkl) everything works fine.

If you dislike the default movement keys, use these mappings:

```
:map <Up> k
:map <Down> j
:map <Left> h
:map <Right> l
```

Comment: Hi Martinho -- I downvoted too: this answer doesn't address the main issue in the original question, which is "why do the arrow keys exit visual mode?"

Comment: From what I see the question reads "How can I..." and was always in that spirit, not in the spirit of "Why ..."

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I don't experience this behavior on Vim 7.1 on Win XP. Perhaps setting nocompatible will help you?