# How can I indent a block of C code in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

#### Duplicate:

> [How to indent code in vim editor in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413208/how-to-indent-code-in-vim-editor-in-windows)
>
> [Tabbing selected section in VIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442302/tabbing-selected-section-in-vim)

Sometimes I want to indent a block of C code in Vim. I usually ended up tabbing it line by line.

What is a better/faster way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413208/how-to-indent-code-in-vim-editor-in-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442302/tabbing-selected-section-in-vim

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm surprised no one came up with `=%` yet.
Make sure you have `:set cindent`,
Place yourself on one of the `{}` of your block, and just hit:

```
=%
```

All code within this block will be correctly indented.

Comment: it indends only one line in my vim. Any idea?

Comment: You're not on one of the {}s.

Comment: @Steve K: I am. Selecting all lines and pressing = works. =% doesn't :(

Comment: @Steve K: Sorry. I misunderstood. I didn't put on the {}. I put inside.

Comment: @skinp: set cindent seams doesn't play any role in this case. Instead you should be aware of set 'equalprg' option to '' to make this work.

Comment: using :he textobjects you could =i{ and not have to be on the specific starting/ending  line of the block

Comment: @michael or =iB (auto-indent inside Block)

Answer (score 8):

Use '>' to tab a block

Comment: After selecting said visual block...

Answer (score 7):

Enter visual mode, select to the next matching bracket, indent:

```
V
%
>
```

Answer (score 4):

While insert: C-d, C-t
While visual: >, <
While normal: >>, <<

In any of this modes use '.' to indent further.

Answer (score 1):

Try

:set cindent

This will turn on C indenting magic in vim.  So as soon as you open a brace, it will automatically tab until you close the brace.

Answer (score 0):

If you have unindented code that looks like this...

```
if (foo)
{
/* line 1 */
/* line 2 */
/* line 3 */
}
```

...place your cursor on "line 1" in command mode and type `3==`, where 3 is the number of lines to indent.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do it without any indent switches being set.

```
:startRange,stopRange s/^/^\t/g
```

should add a tab space at beginning of line between the line number range you provide

unindent with:

```
:startRange,stopRange s/^\t/^/g
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what skinp said, if you have:

```
   int foo()
   {
   /* line 1 */
       /* line 2 */
       /* line 3 */
       /* line 4 */
   }
```

and for whatever reason wish it to look like this (i.e. you want everything indented 4 spaces* from where they were previously, rather than indenting 'correctly' according to the cindent rules):

```
   int foo()
   {
       /* line 1 */
           /* line 2 */
           /* line 3 */
           /* line 4 */
   }
```

anywhere within the block, do viB> (visualselection innerBlock indent)**

`*` or whatever your shiftwidth is set at

`**` vi} is the same as viB, and may be easier to remember since vi} selects within {}, vi) selects within (), vi] selects within [], and vi> selects within <>.

Also, va}, va), etc. select the {}, (), etc in addition to what's contained within the block.