# Indenting a bunch of lines in Vim

Tags: vim, indentation

Is there a way to indent a selection of lines in Vim, like we have in text editors where we select a bunch of lines and press tab (or shift tab) to indent/unindent the selected lines?

I am talking about general indentation and not related to code indentation.

Comment: I made a screencast on this topic: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/indentation-commands/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indent multiple lines quickly in vi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use visual mode [as Peter suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332340/indenting-a-bunch-of-lines-in-vim/2332343#2332343). You can also use <kbd>X>></kbd> where `X` is the number of lines you want to indent. E.g. <kbd>5>></kbd> indents five lines from current line and down.

Comment: One of the things I do most, due to Stack Overflow and writing code examples, is `>G`, to indent from the current position to the end of the file. I write in Ruby generally, so, it's actually `>G.` because Rubyists use two-space indent and SO requires four, but YMMV.

Answer (score 42):

You can select a set of lines with visual line mode (via <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>), and then type

<kbd>></kbd>

and, to dedent,

<kbd><</kbd>

You can also add numeric arguments. Find out you didn't indent enough? Hit <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to re-select your previous selection.

While typing in normal mode, try out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to indent or dedent.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'outdent' instead of 'dedent'?

Comment: @Vinko should be, but isn't :) an outdent is a backwards indent; a dedent is an indent undone. perhaps it should really be undent.

Comment: You don't need to re-select the lines to indent more. Just use the dot command: >... will indent four times.

Comment: I blieve that this should be the accepted answer since Brian's solution, despite correct, is harder to implement.

Comment: @SavasVedova but that is not what the concept of '[accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)' means to convey.

Answer (score 11):

I use the following mappings to indent/unindent:

```
vmap <TAB> >gv
vmap <S-TAB> <gv
```

Use TAB to indent and shift-TAB to unindent the visually selected lines.

If a block is selected Vim indents/unindents what is right of the start of
the block.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by the other answers you can use <kbd>></kbd>. Alternatively, you can automatically correctly indent your code by selecting the set of line in visual mode (using <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>), and then using <kbd>=</kbd>, or using <kbd>==</kbd> to indent the current line.

Answer (score 3):

There's a Vim Cast on this topic: *[Indentation commands](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/indentation-commands/)*

I like Vim Casts. They are informative and pleasant to watch.