# vim indenting a block of code inward and outward

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using mvim . I am trying to map keys so that I could visually select elements then I could indent the code inward or outward. However while doing outward work after every keystroke one more line at the bottom get selected. What is the fix.

```
" Ctrl-x - move the block of visually selected code one tab right and keep visual mode alive
" Ctrl-z moves the data in opposite direction
" Usage : shift v and select multiple lines. then Ctrl x multiple times and
" then Ctrl z multiple times
vmap <C-x> >gv  
vmap <C-z> <gv
```

Comment: You may want to check this related question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332340/indenting-a-bunch-of-lines-in-vim

Answer (score 16):

Why would you go to the trouble when you already can do this?

`>>` - increase indent of selected block

`<<` - decrease indent of selected block

This will cause you to lose the focus.  If you want to continue indenting just type <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat the last action.  You can also type <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to re-select your last selection.

Another option is to select and type a number before indenting, which is the same as repeating the `>>` or `<<` as many times as the number you typed.