# How do I indent a single line multiple times in vi or vim?

Tags: vim, vi, indentation, text-indent

I've found several answers on how to indent multiple lines in vim, I want to know how to take a single line and indent it more than once.  In effect, I want a shorter version of the following command:
">>>>>>>>>>"
(That is 10 right bracket "greater-than" signs.)

Comment: well, you could use `.` to repeat the last command, shortening it to `>>....`

Comment: You could also press `<esc>:>>>>>`

Comment: To be clear, `5>>` will indent five lines, not the current line five times. Strange design choice, as `>4<down>>` does the same thing, and `3>4<down>>` would be a handy way to indent five lines three times.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Select what you want (typically with <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) then type `5>`.

If you need to fix or repeat the same selection, use <kbd>gv</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks ! didn't know about the `gv` shortcut to re-select

Answer (score 16):

One of the answers to ["How do I indent multiple lines quickly in vi"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839) showed me a neat trick to remap `>` in visual mode to reselect visual mode.  In your `.vimrc`...

```
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
```

Then I just select the line (or lines) you want to indent and press the appropriate direction as many times as you want.

Comment: It's a nice trick if you do it all in visual mode, and I like to see the selection afterwards, but I like to use . after the initial modification, which is only in normal mode.

I'm adding this to my .vimrc but mapping them to <TAB> and <S-TAB> instead.

Answer (score 14):

You can select the current line by pressing `v`, and then type `5>` to indent the current line 5 times, the equivalent of pressing `>` 10 times.

Comment: Daenyth is right, but it is moot. You only have to be in visual mode; whether line-select or not is irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 13):

Indent once the use . to redo the previous command or u to undo it.

Answer (score 5):

From `vim` help: `:help >`

> To move a line several 'shiftwidth's, use Visual mode or the : commands.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     Vjj4>           move three lines 4 indents to the right
>     :<<<            move current line 3 indents to the left
>     :>> 5           move 5 lines 2 indents to the right
>     :5>>            move line 5 2 indents to the right
> ```

Or simply, `>>` and repeat the command with `.` in normal mode.