# How can I indent a line by several steps in VIM?

Tags: vim, ide, indentation, vi, neovim

How can I indent a line by several steps in VIM?

To understand my question, see the example blow:

`>>` indents the current line by one step. `2>>` indents two lines by one step Or `V2>` indents the current line by two steps.

Is there any way to repeat this action without going into visual mode?

Comment: `:h shift-left-right`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45988851/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+indent+multiple+times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: `:h shift-left-right`

Answer (score 3):

While in normal mode, you can repeat your last keystroke by using the preiod key(<kbd>.</kbd>).