# Perl: printing Unicode strings to the Windows console

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, console, unicode-string

I am encountering a strange problem in printing Unicode strings to the Windows console*.

Consider this text:

```
אני רוצה לישון

Intermediary

היא רוצה לישון
אתם, הם
Bye
Hello, world!
test
```

Assume it's in a file called "file.txt".

When I go*: "type file.txt", it prints out fine. But when it's printed from a Perl program, like this:

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use Encode;
 use 5.014;
 use utf8;
 use autodie;
 use warnings    qw< FATAL  utf8     >;
 use open        qw< :std  :utf8     >;
 use feature     qw< unicode_strings >;
 use warnings 'all';

 binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';   # output should be in UTF-8
 my $word;
 my @array = ( 'אני רוצה לישון', 'Intermediary',
    'היא רוצה לישון', 'אתם, הם', 'Bye','Hello, world!', 'test');
 foreach $word(@array) {
    say $word;
 }
```

The Unicode lines (Hebrew in this case) show up again each time, partially broken, like this:

```
E:\My Documents\Technical\Perl>perl "hello unicode.pl"
אני רוצה לישון
לישון
�ן

Intermediary
היא רוצה לישון
לישון
�ן

אתם, הם
�ם

Bye
Hello, world!
test
```

(I save everything in UTF-8).

This is mighty strange. Any suggestions?

(It's not a "Console2" problem* - the same problem shows up on a "regular" windows console, only there you don't see the Hebrew glyphs).

---

* Using "Console" (also called "Console2") - it's a nice little utility which enables working with Unicode with the Windows console - see, for example, here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx

** Note: at the console, you have to say, of course:

```
chcp 65001
```

Comment: Oof. Please just use the four-space code formatting rather than all those `<br>`, `<code>` tags all over the place.

Comment: These **are** Unicode strings, represented in UTF-8. Please cancel your -1.

Comment: Sorry to waste all the effort escaping code, but in Markdown, all you have to do to format code is indent it with 4 spaces. You can also just press the code button `{}` in the editor toolbar. (@sarnold: Fixed!)

Comment: Got it. @sarnold: please explain: "four space code formatting"?

Comment: Helen: take a look at how @minitech reformatted your post in the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9370720/revisions) (available on every post via the "edited N minutes ago" link) -- it's far easier to modify in the future, copy-and-paste elsewhere, and uses a neater formatting style. Minitech, many thanks. Again. :)

Comment: Just put at least four spaces in front of a line. The markdown parser will think it's something to present in the code style. Generally, I type out my post in a text editor then shift the code bits over one indent level before I paste it in.

Comment: Is your file actually saved as UTF-8? You've told Perl that it is with the `utf8` pragma, but if it's not actually encoded as that, things might get messed up.

Comment: Affirmative. The file **is** actually saved in UTF-8. In addition, "binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';" makes sure it is.

Comment: @briandfoy How do you shift the code bits in your text editor?

Comment: @TLP - depends on code editor. In mine (UltraEdit), you select the text and press "TAB" key or an "Indent" icon. I'm sure Emacs and vi have some easy way as well.

Comment: @DVK I use vim, and I've been looking for a shortcut to add/remove indent.

Comment: @DVK Ah, cool, guess I just needed a quick google session. `<` and `>`, how simple.

Comment: @TLP - if only there was a web site where a person could ask a programming related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/how-do-i-indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi)... :)))))   ( the highest voted answer lists `>` command )

Comment: @DVK Awesome! That post was pure gold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try the solution from [perlmonk](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=871945) ?

It use `:unix` as well to avoid the console buffer.

This is the code from that link:

```
use Win32::API;

binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:utf8");

#Must set the console code page to UTF8
$SetConsoleOutputCP= new Win32::API( 'kernel32.dll', 'SetConsoleOutputCP', 'N','N' );
$SetConsoleOutputCP->Call(65001);

$line1="\x{2554}".("\x{2550}"x15)."\x{2557}\n";
$line2="\x{2551}".(" "x15)."\x{2551}\n";
$line3="\x{255A}".("\x{2550}"x15)."\x{255D}";
$unicode_string=$line1.$line2.$line3;

print "THIS IS THE CORRECT EXAMPLE OUTPUT IN PURE PERL: \n";
print $unicode_string;
```

Comment: Wow - lots of interesting stuff. I will study it, try it and report back.

Comment: She already sets the console to cp 65001, so what's new in that post?

Comment: @J-16-SDiZ Thanks guys - it worked beautifully. It still threw the error: `"Global symbol "$SetConsoleOutputCP" requires explicit package name"`, but that has been easily corrected by replacing it with: `Win32::$SetConsoleOutputCP`.

Comment: @ikegami: it's not sufficient to chcp 65001. The Windows console buffer and the Perl buffering do not agree, and you must specify: `binmode(STDOUT, ":unix:utf8");` (instead of: `binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");` ) for Perl Unicode output to Windows console to work.

Comment: --Previous comment should go: `$Win32::SetConsoleOutputCP` and not: `Win32::$SetConsoleOutputCP`.

Answer (score 3):

Guys: continuing on studying that Perlmonks post, turns out that this is even neater and  nicer:
replace:  
`use Win32::API;`

and:

```
$SetConsoleOutputCP= new Win32::API( 'kernel32.dll', 'SetConsoleOutputCP', 'N','N' );
$SetConsoleOutputCP->Call(65001);
```

with:

```
use Win32::Console;
```

and:

```
 Win32::Console::OutputCP(65001);
```

Leaving all else intact.
This is even more in the spirit of Perl conciseness and magic.

Comment: In addition one must change the font of cmd.exe to "Consolas" to be able to see the unicode characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can also utilize [Win32::Unicode::Console](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aUnicode%3a%3aConsole) or [Win32::Unicode::Native](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aUnicode%3a%3aNative) to achieve unicode prints on windows console.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this behaviour is not present while using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/), which also enables proper Unicode support in Windows' command console.