# How do I indent a particular block of code in Vim?

Tags: vim, format

In [Aptana Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptana#Aptana_Studio) when I have to format code I choose a block of code and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

What is the equivalent of this in Vim?

I.e., say we got the below lines of code:

```
function() {
var test = "Hello, World!";
var test2 = "Hello, World! Again";
}
```

The final output I want to see is well formatted code like below:

```
function(){
  var test = "Hello, World!";
  var test2 = "Hello, World! Again";
}
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/235839/how-do-i-indent-multiple-lines-quickly-in-vi?rq=1)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If Vim knows the language you are using, you can use the `=` key to auto-indent a section of code.

Within the block type `=a}`, or to auto-indent the entire file by typing `gg=G`.

Comment: This is the coolest thing I've seen today so far!!!

Answer (score 5):

Use `>i{` (right-shift inside current block), or better yet, `=a{` (properly indent the current block), plus having a proper indent mode enabled (e.g. `:set cindent`).

If you're opening up a whole file that's badly indented, you might want to start off with `gg=G` (re-indent the whole file).

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
set shiftwidth=2
```

to indent with two spaces, as I can see in your example, and then:

```
V
```

to insert in visual mode block,

```
j
```

to go one line down and select both,

```
>
```

to indent once.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get to normal mode.
- Select with <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd>, and then <kbd>></kbd>.
- <kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to indent one line.
- <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>></kbd> or <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>></kbd> if you want to indent multiple times.

Check `:help shiftwidth` to set how many spaces your indentation will be.